# Installed some new software and added a user, now my first user crashes X and can't login

Tags: 12.04, ati, xorg, xubuntu

I am running Xubuntu 12.04. I installed dogecoind and made a new user called dogecoin. My first user, james, used to be the only one.  It used to be set to auto log in. Now I have a choice between my two users and guest.  If I try to login as james the screen flashes black and resets, then sends me back to login.  I can still login fine with the others.

I can login to james through SSH where I tried to reset my x config files. It didn't seem to help.

```
sudo aticonfig --adapter=all -f --initial
```

It says:

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Uninitialised file found, configuring.
Using `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`
Saving back-up to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.fglrx-6
```

`pacman -Qi linux` says:

```
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
no display possible
```

I am trying to use two graphics cards, but I can't even login!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file ~/.Xauthority from user's home folder.

Also try to delete /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Re-install xorg

Reboot